# How do I use UIBezierPath to draw a line that follows a touch event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I picked up the following piece of code from a similar question but I'm not having any luck getting it to work.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"Check #1");

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    currentPath.lineWidth = 3.0;
    [currentPath moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
    [paths addObject:self.currentPath];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self.currentPath addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    for (UIBezierPath *path in paths) {
        NSLog(@"Check #2?");
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

What I've got from it is that I need to use `UIBezierPath` but I'm not sure how to get it to follow my finger. I only want to draw a line, start it when the user touches down and end it where they pick up their finger.

How can I achieve this line drawing using UIBezierPath?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Canvas : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint location;

@end




#import "Canvas.h"

@implementation Canvas

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.location = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.location.x, self.location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.location = currentLocation;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.location.x, self.location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.location = currentLocation;
}

@end
```

Comment: On a side note, it's probably redundant to use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() that many times. Declare a CGContextRef variable and reference that instead.

Comment: Yeah probably. This was just an old example I found in my catalogue. I've never used it for anything other that in the early days of figuring out Core Graphics. (I've updated the example)

Comment: I guess UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() should go between UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() and UIGraphicsEndImageContext(), otherwise it's NULL.

Comment: Yup, probably should. I moved it.

Comment: Why do I get an incompatible pointer types error on the `CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];` (pointing at the `self` bit)?

Comment: Have you copied these methods somewhere else where self isn't a UIView or subclass of UIView. My Canvas class extends UIImageView which is a UIView. What is the superclass of the class where you have pasted this code? More than likely it is NSObject or something else.

Comment: Do not forget to add imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES. Default value is NO which means the view till not respond to touches.

Comment: What if I want to add to cgcontextaddlinetopoint with intelligence like the apps which blur the background based on the user selection?