# doodle on UIView - ios development

Tags: ios, uiview, touch, quartz-graphics

Hello I am working on this project to allow user doodle on a UIView. My approach is creating an CGMutablePathRef path and adding new lines to it while TouchMoved.

The codes relevant are listed below, which are in class of UIView.

```
static CGMutablePathRef path; //create it as static value. 
//I got this habit from java coding but actually not sure 
//if it's a good way to do it in objective-c.


//draw the path

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}

//touch began. create the path and add point.
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];            
}


//add points when touch moved
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

//last points when touch ends
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

However, I got errors and I didn't really understand them... I guess it's something with UIGestureRecognizer, which I saw from other doodle codes. Is it necessary to add UIGestureRecognizer to it? I haven't learned anything about it so I was trying to avoid using it. But if it's a must, I will give a try.

Another approach I am thinking of is to store all the point positions to an mutable array, because I have to store these point position values somewhere. However, I don't know if array is suitable because I haven't find a way to store floating values to the array. It will be greatly helpful if anyone can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: There's no need for using UIGestureRecognizers. As for storing floats to NSMutableArray take a look at [[NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) numberWithFloat:]. Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393058/how-do-i-use-uibezierpath-to-draw-a-line-that-follows-a-touch-event

Comment: I'd recommend to use a gesture recognizer. It makes your code simpler and easier to extend.

Comment: @rokjarc Yes the linked question is very helpful. One more small question: the class used in that answer is UIImageView so in the methods it calls [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)]. But in my case it's UIView, so what method should I call to draw? (Sorry I guess it's a silly question. I am really a newb.) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to guys who offered me help. After looking thru a bunch of codes and approaches, luckily I found the effective way to solve this problem!

Generally, the imageView in my SketchView is updated dynamically when I am drawing. That is, every time I drew more pixel, one line will be added to that new pixel, change the UIImageView and then set it as the background image of UIView.

SketchView.h

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint CurrentPoint;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint PreviousPoint;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint InitialPoint;
```

SketchView.m

```
@synthesize CurrentPoint;
@synthesize PreviousPoint;
@synthesize InitialPoint;


//begin the touch. store the initial point because I want to connect it to the last   
//touch point
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:image];
    InitialPoint = point;

    }


//When touch is moving, draw the image dynamically
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
PreviousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:image];
CurrentPoint = [touch locationInView:image];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.frame.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
[image.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.frame.size.width,   image.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, PreviousPoint.x, PreviousPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CurrentPoint.x, CurrentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
image.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}



- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
PreviousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:image];
CurrentPoint = [touch locationInView:image];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.frame.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, PreviousPoint.x, PreviousPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CurrentPoint.x, CurrentPoint.y);

//I connected the last point to initial point to make a closed region
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CurrentPoint.x, CurrentPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, InitialPoint.x, InitialPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
image.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

And it works!

p.s. I found

```
 PreviousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:image];
```

very helpful, though it's not mentioned much in the codes I found doing doodling... I hope this helps. :)