# UIBezierPath to draw a line that follows a touch, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to convert [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393412/265692) to Swift, but I'm not sure what to do about this line:

```
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: To be more specific, I'm not sure what self.image is in the answer I linked to.

Comment: For what it's worth, that is a very bad way to draw a line following touch events. Instead, have touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded create an array of `CGPoint` values and send setNeedsDisplay to the layer every time the array changes. Then inside the layer's drawInContext delegate method, enumerate the list of points and draw the line, possibly with some fancy stuff like increasing the line width depending how close to the start/end of the line you are and using quad curve bezier paths to smooth it out nicely. Plenty of tutorials online demonstrating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Canvas` class in that answer is a subclass of `UIImageView`, so the `self.image` in that line is the inherited `image` property, of type `UIImage`. In Swift the converted line could be something like:

```
self.image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
```

Comment: when I do that on a custom UIIMageView class I get this: fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Comment: this line gives fatal error: Can't unwrap optional value can you pls tell whats wrong with it.

Comment: `self.image` is an implicitly unwrapped Optional - make sure it's not `nil` before you do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like

```
self.image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
```

or

```
self.tempDrawImg.image .drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like

```
self.image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
```

or

```
self.tempDrawImg.image .drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
```

so that the full code becomes

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
self.tempDrawImg.image .drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5.0
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.location.x, self.location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```