# Swift: Drawing a UIBezierPath based on touch in a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I've been looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393058/how-do-i-use-uibezierpath-to-draw-a-line-that-follows-a-touch-event) as I'm trying to implement the same thing. However, I see that the Canvas class is implemented as a subclass of UIImageView. I'm trying to do the same thing except in a UIView. How will using a UIView rather than UIImageView affect the implementation of this solution? I see `self.image` used a couple times, but I don't know how I'd change that since I don't think that is available in a generic UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can implement this as a `UIView` subclass. Your model should hold the locations of the touch events (or the paths constructed from those locations) and then the `drawRect` of the view can render these paths. Or you create `CAShapeLayer` objects associated with those paths, too. Both approaches work fine.

Note, there is some merit to the approach of making snapshots (saved as `UIImage`) objects that you either show in a `UIImageView` or manually draw in `drawRect` of your `UIView` subclass. As your drawings get more and more complicated, you'll start to suffer performance issues if your `drawRect`  has to redraw all of path segments (it can become thousands of locations surprisingly quickly because there are a lot of touches associated with a single screen gesture) upon every touch.

IMHO, I think that other answer you reference goes too far, making a new snapshot upon every `touchesMoved`. When you look at full resolution image for retina iPad or iPhone 6 plus, that's a large image snapshot to create upon every touch event. I personally adopt a hybrid approach: My `drawRect` or `CAShapeLayer` will render the current path associated with the current gesture (or the collection of `touchesMoved` events between `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`), but when the gesture finishes, it will create a new snapshot.

Comment: If I use a UIImage and make snapshots, would I be able to edit the shapes that have already been drawn? It sounds to me that if they were in an image, they wouldn't be editable, I'd only be able to draw more things on top of them and not remove anything I've already drawn. That's a key feature for what I want to do, so if that's not possible I'll have to do it with a UIView.

Comment: Obviously, the snapshot wouldn't be editable (beyond pixel editing, of course). But if you keep your model objects (e.g. the paths) used in the generation of that snapshot, you can edit your model and then theoretically regenerate the snapshot at any point. Thus, I'm suggesting that the snapshot is not the model (as that accepted answer to that other question would seem to imply), but rather merely a rendering optimization that saves you from redrawing all of the old paths every time the model is updated.

Comment: So save an image, perhaps, every time I create a new bezier path, and then every time I add a new path I make a new image from the image and the path? So then rather than having to rerender a bezier path with a huge potential number of points, I instead only have to render the image, which is simply the specified pixels?

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can figure out, thanks for your help!

Comment: Another related question, how will this be affected by other tap gesture recognizers I have in the view? I have a couple UIButtons that cause TapGestureRecognizers to be made that will create a shape upon tapping, and then remove the recognizer. If I do this, will it mess with the touches... functions of the UIView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65991/discussion-between-rob-and-user1493950).

Answer (score 0):

In the answer to that question, self.image is drawn into the drawing context first, then drawing is applied on top, then finally the image is updated to be the old image with new content drawn on top.

Since you just want to add a UIBezierPath, I'd just create a CAShapeLayer into which you place your bezier path, and place it on top of your views backing layer (self.view.layer).  There's no need to do anything with DrawRect.