# Draw a line to connect two circles

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, quartz-2d

I'm building a customized user interface input which let the user connect two circle with each other through a line.

This is what the prototype looks like

[image]

I'm wondering how could I draw the straight line? UIViews? SpriteKit? or what?

Comment: `CAShapeLayer` would be the simplest.

Comment: Here is a Question how to use UIBezierPath to draw lines : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393058/how-do-i-use-uibezierpath-to-draw-a-line-that-follows-a-touch-event?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIBezierPath()` and `CAShapeLayer()`.

#### This function should do the trick:

```
func drawLineFromPoint(point1:CGPoint, point2:CGPoint) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(point1)
    path.addLineToPoint(point2)
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This function would draw static line between two points. I'm looking for *interactive line* to be pulled from point to another.

Comment: So, to be drawn every frame, while dragging, from the start point, to the current point, where your finger is located?

Answer (score 0):

no cache version:

```
class LineView:UIView {

    var startP: CGPoint?
    var endP: CGPoint?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.locationInView(self);

        //do some matching here...

        self.startP = location
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.locationInView(self);
        self.endP = location
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.locationInView(self);

        //do some matching here...

        self.endP = location
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        if let start = self.startP {
            if let end = self.endP {
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y)
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y)
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
                CGContextStrokePath(context)
            }
        }
    }
}
```